# React router not allowing images to load

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am using react-router for the first time and I am having a little problem with my project. React-router is changing the url fine, but then my images are not getting loaded. I believe it is because the base url changes, for example it works when the link it's like this: `http://localhost:3000/f0287893b2bcc6566ac48aa6102cd3b1.png` but it doesn't when it's like this `http://localhost:3000/module/f0287893b2bcc6566ac48aa6102cd3b1.png`. Here is my router code:

```
import { Router, Route, browserHistory, IndexRoute } from 'react-router'
import { syncHistoryWithStore } from 'react-router-redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import React from 'react'

import App from './containers/App'
import configure from './store'
import Home from './components/home';
import Module from './components/module-page/module';
import Login from './components/login/login';

const store = configure();
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={Login} />
        <Router path="/home" component={Home}/>
        <Router path="/module(/:module)" component={Module}/>
      </Route>
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

this is where the link is triggered:

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
  import { ROUTE_MODULE } from '../../constants/Routes';
  import { Link } from 'react-router';
  import styles from './side-bar-items.css';
  import { Navbar, Nav, NavItem, Collapse } from 'react-bootstrap/lib'
  import FontAwesome from 'react-fontawesome';
  
  class SideBarItems extends Component {
  
    constructor(prop) {
      super(prop);
      this.state = { open: false };
    }
  
    render() {
  
      return (
        <Navbar.Collapse>
          <Nav>
            <NavItem className={styles.navItem} eventKey={1}>
              <FontAwesome className={styles.navItemIcon} name='globe' size="lg"/>
               <span className={styles.navItemIconText}>Dashboard</span>
            </NavItem>
            <NavItem onClick={this.showModules} className={`${styles.navItem} ${styles.itemModule}`}>
              <FontAwesome className={styles.navItemIcon} name='clone' size="lg"/>
              <span className={styles.navItemIconText}>Modules</span>
              <Collapse in={this.state.open}>
                <div className={styles.collapse}>
                  <div className={styles.module}>
                    <Link to="/module/moduleCode=2999">Programming III</Link>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </Collapse>
            </NavItem>
          </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      )
    }
  
    showModules = () => {
      this.setState({ open: !this.state.open })
    }
  }
  
  export default (SideBarItems);
```

This is where I import the image:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Image from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Image'
import avatar from '../../images/avatar.jpg';
import styles from './user-image.css';

class UserImage extends Component {

render() {

  return (
    <div className={styles.userContainer}>
      <Image className={styles.avatar} src={avatar} rounded />
      <span className={styles.userName}>Hello, Daniel</span>
      <span className={styles.userCourse}>SEC, Software Engineering</span>
    </div>
  )
}
}

export default (UserImage);
```

this is how the website looks when I click on the link

[image]

Comment: Could you try `<Image className={styles.avatar} src={\`/${avatar}\`} rounded />`?

Comment: Yepp worked. Thanks!

Comment: Nice, I'll prepare an answer so it can help others.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

To make sure that the image is taken from the root of the server and not the relative directory of the current route, add a `/` in front of the `src`:

```js
<Image className={styles.avatar} src={`/${avatar}`} rounded />
```

Comment: Not working for me. I am using `react js` in `cordova` in ES5 version

Comment: Don't forget to put your images under the public folder :). I had mine in a static folder under src/ before I realized they should of been under public.

Answer (score 43):

What worked for me was to set the HTML base reference to the web root

```
<head>
    <base href="/">
</head>
```

this also solved some other problems with the router when refreshing the page at a predetermined route.

Comment: Genius. Top tip this!

Comment: This should be the new accepted answer because it works globally for the project. Omitting the need to change the routes

Comment: the most elegant solution by far

Comment: You save me a lot of headache

Comment: ultimate solution.Just use it without second thought.

Comment: Also notice this noob tip (future visitors): When you put your images under `/public/foo` then you will have to start your image paths with `foo/`, e.g., `foo/some.jpg`.

Comment: Genious tip.
God bless you bro.

Answer (score 3):

maybe you can set the base element in your html file.

```
<base href="http://www.example.com/page.html">
```

Answer (score 1):

you should add the  in the public/index.html so that the images can be loaded from the base server instead of relative path..